# definite article with a generic noun as an answer for superlative question

Tags: definite-article, superlatives

Is it a mistake to answer like that?

> What food is the most delicious?  - *It is the apple.*

Comment: You should describe the research that you've already done on this issue. Also, instead of simply asking whether a sentence is correct (which may be considered a proofreading request, which is off-topic), please indicate why you think that it may contain an error.

Comment: because it sounds very unnatural and I've never heard someone answered like that.

Comment: It would be more natural to say "[I think] the apple is."

Comment: Why is "It is the apple." not correct? For instance, A:-Which film is the most famous? B:It is the Titanic. Isn't this answer the same structure? If this answer is correct, why would the one in the question not be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is very unnatural, and you'll never hear an answer like that.

So while there is no grammatical error, and the meaning is clear enough, this is not a good way to answer a superlative question.

Normally the answer would not be a complete sentence:

> What is the largest planet?
>
> Jupiter.

If you need a full sentence, make the answer the subject, and repeat the question.

> What is the largest planet?
>
> Jupiter is the largest planet.